# Sort list of strings by multiple parts of the string

Tags: python, string, sorting

I have a list of strings which have the following format:

```
['XXX_A-BXXX', 'XXX_A-BXXX', 'XXX_A-BXXX', 'XXX_A-BXXX', ...]

A=['C1','C2','C3','T1','T2', 'T3']
B=['3s','6m','1h','8h','24h']
XXX = random combination of alphabets and numbers
```

... and I want to sort the list based on the A part and then B part by the orders above. How would I go about doing this?

For some real sample inputs, this is what I want to get:

```
['Vout_C1-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_C1-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_C1-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_C1-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_C1-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-24hNP-N']
```

---

Thanks all for answering. I also came up with a method but it seems I can't answer my own question so I just put it here.

```
lst_strings = [...]
pairs = [re.split('[_\-NP]', file)[1:3] for file in lst_strings] # get A part and B part
groups = [pair[0] for pair in pairs] # A part
times = [t[1].replace('3', '3-6s') if t[1]=='3' else t[1] for t in pairs] # B part (previous split messed up '3-6s')

sorted_groups = [str(a)+str(x) for a in ['C','T'] for x in range(1,5)] # ['C1','C2',...,'T1','T2',...]
sorted_times = ['3-6s','6m','1h','8h','24h']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst_strings, groups, times)), columns=['data', 'group', 'time'])
df1 = pd.concat([df.loc[df['time']==sorted_times[i]] for i in range(len(sorted_times))])
df2 = pd.concat([df1.loc[df1['group']==sorted_groups[i]] for i in range(len(sorted_groups))])
lst_sorted = df2['data'].values
```

Comment: can you share some real sample inputs, the code you've tried so far, the error you're getting, and the expected output?

Comment: Look into Schwartzian transform: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Creating two sort keys for your two conditions seems a good approach:

```
def multiple_sort(value):
    first, second = value.split('-', 1)
    # first key is `C1`, C2` etc.
    key1 = first.split('_')[-1]
    # use this order for second sort key
    names = ['3-6s', '6m', '1h', '8h', '24h']
    key2 = len(names) # last if not found
    for pos, name in enumerate(names):
        if second.startswith(name):
            key2 = pos
            break
    return key1, key2
```

Test it on your data:

```
data = ['Vout_C1-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_C1-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_C1-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_C1-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_C1-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-24hNP-N']
```

Make the order random:

```
import random
random.shuffle(data)
```

Look at the result:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(sorted(data, key=multiple_sort))
```

Output:

```
['Vout_C1-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_C1-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_C1-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_C1-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_C1-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_T1-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-24hNP-N']
```

## Explanation

Looking at some example strings:

```
data[:10]

['Vout_C1-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-1hNP-N',
 'Vout_C2-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_C1-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_T3-6mNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-24hNP-N',
 'Vout_C3-3-6sNP-N',
 'Vout_C1-8hNP-N',
 'Vout_T2-6mNP-N']
```

the function `multiple_sort()`generates these values:

```
[multiple_sort(x) for x in data[:10]]

[('C1', 2),
 ('C2', 2),
 ('C2', 3),
 ('T2', 4),
 ('C1', 0),
 ('T3', 1),
 ('C3', 4),
 ('C3', 0),
 ('C1', 3),
 ('T2', 1)]
```

Now:

```
sorted(data, key=multiple_sort)
```

use these keys for sorting. i.e. it sorts first by the first key `C1`, `C2` etc. and if these are equal by the second key `2`, `2`, `3`, `4` etc.

Comment: Beautiful work!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using the regex from @chrisz answer

```
import re
from random import shuffle

def customOrderKey(e):
    matches = re.findall(r'[A-Z]\d-(\d+-\d+[mhs]|\d+[mhs])', e)
    return '' if len(matches) == 0 else matches[0]

x = ['Vout_C1-3-6sNP-N', 'Vout_C1-6mNP-N', 'Vout_C1-1hNP-N', 'Vout_C1-8hNP-N', 'Vout_C1-24NP-N', 'Vout_C2-3-6sNP-N', 'Vout_C2-6mNP-N', 'Vout_C2-1hNP-N', 'Vout_C2-8hNP-N', 'Vout_C2-24NP-N', 'Vout_C3-3-6sNP-N', 'Vout_C3-6mNP-N', 'Vout_C3-1hNP-N', 'Vout_C3-8hNP-N', 'Vout_C3-24NP-N', 'Vout_T1-3-6sNP-N', 'Vout_T1-6mNP-N', 'Vout_T1-1hNP-N', 'Vout_T1-8hNP-N', 'Vout_T1-24NP-N', 'Vout_T2-3-6sNP-N', 'Vout_T2-6mNP-N', 'Vout_T2-1hNP-N', 'Vout_T2-8hNP-N', 'Vout_T2-24NP-N', 'Vout_T3-3-6sNP-N', 'Vout_T3-6mNP-N', 'Vout_T3-1hNP-N', 'Vout_T3-8hNP-N', 'Vout_T3-24NP-N']

shuffle(x) # shuffling just to check the code

order = ['3-6s', '6m', '1h', '8h', '24h', '']
x.sort(key=(lambda x: x[5:])) # sort by A
x.sort(key=(lambda x: order.index(customOrderKey(x)))) # sort by B
```

Note: Python's sort is stable so the order of the sorts doesn't matter

Comment: Nice use of multiple sorts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just had a go at this ....

So I start off generating data (as you do not provide enough)

```
from random import randint

def rnd_3_char():
    return chr(65+randint(0,25))+chr(65+randint(0,25))+chr(65+randint(0,25))

def gen_data():
    A=['C1','C2','C3','T1','T2', 'T3']
    B=['3s','4s','5s','6m','1h','8h','24h']
    return "{}_{}_{}".format(rnd_3_char(),A[randint(0,len(A)-1)],B[randint(0,len(B)-1)])
```

I put this into a list called data...

```
data=[gen_data() for a in range(500)]
```

The top ten record look something like this....

['YTI_T1_5s',
 'ZHB_T2_8h',
 'RRN_C3_6m',
 'VLW_C1_4s',
 'AUP_T3_6m',
 'OFU_T1_4s',
 'XTE_C2_5s',
 'VQV_T3_8h',
 'NIC_C3_4s',
 'RLC_T2_8h']

Which seems to meet your requirements.

Now Custom Sort ... I will split the data into 3

So RLC_T2_8h becomes RLC T2 8h.

Now using a regex I internally calculate the seconds of the 3rd value, and along with the 1st value return these to the sort function.

```
import re

def my_sort(a):
    sec_cnt=0
    parts=a.split('_')
    match=re.findall('([0-9]+)([shm])',parts[2])
    try:
        if match[0][1]=='s':
            sec_cnt=int(match[0][0])
        elif match[0][1]=='m':
            sec_cnt=60*int(match[0][0])
        elif match[0][1]=='h':
            sec_cnt=3600*int(match[0][0])
    except:
        #print("{}".format(parts[1]))
        pass

    return parts[1],sec_cnt
```

So using this

```
data2=sorted(data,key=my_sort)
data2[:10]
```

Returns

['BBM_C1_3s',
 'TSD_C1_3s',
 'YZR_C1_3s',
 'HJL_C1_3s',
 'TNU_C1_3s',
 'LYK_C1_3s',
 'MYT_C1_3s',
 'FFX_C1_3s',
 'XDB_C1_3s',
 'BVB_C1_3s',
 'LYD_C1_3s',
 'NIM_C1_3s',
 'NBU_C1_3s',

Hope this is close enough